# GNOME Boxes: How to expose battery to guest OS?

Tags: virtualization, battery, kvm-virtualization, qemu, gnome-boxes

I'm running a couple VMs via GNOME Boxes (libvirt qemu/kvm) on a Dell XPS 13.
Unfortunately, these guest operating systems don't seem to understand they are running on notebook hardware, and hence do not display any sort of battery indicators or power management utilities.

Is there a way to "expose" the battery of my host system to the guest systems?

A host-side solution would be ideal, but a guest-side solution for Linux VMs would also work just as well.

Comment: Hi, I think you are waiting on this feature request to be fully implemented => https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1502613 - until then you can trick it via a custom acpi table as outlined at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF (search for battery).

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt thanks for your comments. Unfortunately the suggestions in the Arch Wiki are wrong, and those proposed edits fail validation. However, there's similar mentions in the libvirt xml domain specification here: https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html.

Comment: That said, editing the `<os></os>` section to include `<acpi><table type="slic">/path/to/slic.dat</table></acpi>` passes validation, but doesn't appear to pass a battery through to the guest.

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt Thanks for the link. It worked in exposing the battery file but the values of files within do not match the current state of host

Comment: This might be ridiculous, but what if you used sonali's answer below, and then use a combo of folder sharing and bind mounts to pass through /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0 from the host into the VM? I have no clue if this would be accurate or if it would work, and it may have security implications, but that might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the complete answer you are looking for. So as mentioned by @christianEhrhardt, i used the same link but slightly different.

So instead of updating domain, i launched VM using command line option `-acpitable`

- Created the SSDT1.dat file from https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF (search battery)
- Launched the VM using following command :

```
sudo qemu <other-options> -acpitable file=/path/to/SSDT1.dat
```

The only challenge here is it keeps showing guest battery capacity 100% even if host is below 100%. So to my understanding, this is not exposing host battery instead launching guest with a fake battery device.

Source : https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/ebo2uk/nvidia_geforce_rtx_2060_mobile_success_qemu_ovmf/

Host :

```
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity
87
```

Guest :

```
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity
100
```

If someone finds answer to how host actual battery info be exposed to guest, your comment will help.